# Extract data after a special character in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to extract anything that is after the underscore

Data

```
id  type
a   h_bu
a   zz_db
b   v_ssc
c   i_db-nd
c   i_db-nd
```

Desired

```
id  type    alias
a   h_bu    bu
a   zz_db   db
b   v_ssc   ssc
c   i_db-nd db
c   i_db-nd db
```

Doing

```
df['number']=df['number'].str.split('_').str[-2:].str.join('_')
```

I am using the str.split method here, however, my other columns are not maintained.
I am still troubleshooting. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I think the alias for the type `i_db-nd` should be `db-nd`? And I don't see any column named `number` in your sample dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean by 'my other columns are not maintained'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
df['alias'] = df['type'].str.extract(r"(?<=_)([\w]+)") # OR r"(?<=_)([a-z]+)"
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  id     type alias
0  a     h_bu    bu
1  a    zz_db    db
2  b    v_ssc   ssc
3  c  i_db-nd    db
4  c  i_db-nd    db
```